# From installed file ,how to find which msi would have installed the file?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, orca

My manager gave me the list of config files from the machine where the msi are installed.

And he asked me to find from which msi they came from . (because we need to write some logic for that msi).

How to find from which msi this files came from ?

Opening in orca manually and search it is tough as number of msi is more.

is there any other alternative approach? we are using Wix for creating msi.

Answer (score 1):

I would get the MD5 hash of the .config files then query the MsiFileHash table in your .msis until I found a matching hash.

Comment: It's a shame that MSI doesn't have a feature like RPM (rpm -qf).

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that an MSI installed the file.  That said, one quick hack that I've used a lot is the ms-dos findstr command

On a machine with the config files installed:

```
CD %WINDIR%\Installer
FINDSTR -i -m dark.exe *.msi *.msi
```

This will do a case insensitive search of across all MSI files for the string dark.exe.   Then use ORCA to inspect the resultant MSI(s) to see if the hit is accurate and what product it is.  Reminder: The MSI name will be some short hex hash as these are the stripped / cached MSI's not the original MSI's.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run code on the machine, then a utility that uses the Windows Installer API will give you the answer(s). Such utilities are easily written in VC++.

A starting point with the Windows Installer APIs is [MsiEnumComponents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will give you a component code for every component installed on the system. From there, `MsiEnumClients` will give you a product code for every product that includes a particular component. Then you can use `MsiGetComponentPath` to get the component's path. If it's a path that you are interested in, then use [MsiGetProductInfoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out about the product that installed it, such as `INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLSOURCE` and `INSTALLPROPERTY_PACKAGENAME.`

It sounds complicated but it's not.